# Changing Layout Activity gets my app very slow

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm not very experienced in android. In my `LayoutActivity`, I have a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation includes two `TextView` and `ListView` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/not_connected_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#01132e"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Not Connected.."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/global_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_info_accent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
        android:text="Today"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ChatlistView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I changed my layout by putting one `TextView` and the `ListView` inside a  `RelativeLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/not_connected_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#01132e"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Not Connected.."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/global_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_info_accent"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:text="Today" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ChatlistView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

After this modification my `ListView` is now scrolling very very slow. Can any one help me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible you changed something else besides the xml? You might try changing layout_width, layout_height values to "0dp" for the ListView  as they are conflicting with the the "align" directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the Textview will be presented over the Listview that may cause to hide part of its first element, I guess when you scroll down, the system needs to regenerate the view each time which will take time. No other rational justification AFAIK.

Edit: 
You should add `AlignParentTop` to the TextView and set height of `ListView` to `MatchParent`.

Besides if you want the TextView to be on the top of ListView swap the definition of them in the XML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But can you explain what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: yehhh , thank you very much it worked and the listView scrolled smoothly.